# Read an array and merge new new agaist same key and value php

Tags: php

```
  $merged = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_data_res)){
    $merged[] = $row;
  }


echo '<pre>'; print_r($merged); echo '</pre>';
```

After  Printing Array I am getting this output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [lees_than_60] => 50
            [one_four] => 48
            [four_min] => 0
            [id] => 24
            [first_name] => Yogini
            [log_in_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [log_out_time] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [calldate] => 2014-05-22
            [clid] => 2433
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [lees_than_60] => 14
            [one_four] => 6
            [four_min] => 2
            [id] => 28
            [first_name] => Vijay
            [log_in_time] => 2014-05-28 16:57:51
            [log_out_time] => 2014-05-28 16:58:12
            [calldate] => 2014-05-22
            [clid] => 2436
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [lees_than_60] => 64
            [one_four] => 60
            [four_min] => 0
            [id] => 23
            [first_name] => Pratibha
            [log_in_time] => 2014-05-28 15:55:18
            [log_out_time] => 2014-05-28 15:55:44
            [calldate] => 2014-05-22
            [clid] => 2431
        )
)
```

My question is I want to create below array like I want to create new array against same calldate 2014-05-22 ie only one calldate and remaining all data like:

> [calldate] => 2014-05-22

show whole data of aove call date should not repeat by merging

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Can you show example array you want to create?

Comment: Show data Against same key and value against calldate @Peter

Comment: Can you show example array you want to create? –

Comment: Array (
   [0] => Array (
          [cust] => XT8900
          [type] => standard
          [level] => 1
          )
   [1] => Array (
          [cust] => XT8944
          [type] => standard
          [level] => 1
          )
   [2] => Array (
          [cust] => XT8922
          [type] => premier
          [level] => 3
          )
   [3] => Array (
          [cust] => XT8816
          [type] => permier
          [level] => 3
          )
   [4] => Array (
          [cust] => XT7434
          [type] => standard
          [level] => 7
          )
)

Comment: where did you get this "XT8900" "standard" "1" ??? it's completely different array